# Getting destination ViewController from UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have programmed UIBarButtonItem so that it does some action before switching to a previous view. I was wondering how do I get the viewcontroller of that transitioning scene from my UIBarButtonItem?
So, scene 1 -> scene 2 (current scene) -> scene 1 (after clicking the UIBarButtonItem button)

I've tried to pass the previous scene variables (that I need) to the current scene to perform action on (sense I don't think the transitioning scene is instantiating a new view, but that doesn't work

````
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadTuple()
        let addButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveExercise(_: )))
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(addButton, animated: true)

    }
    @objc func saveExercise(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.addNewTupleToDB(element: self.getNewTuple())
        self.saveData()
        debugPrint("saveExercise")
        self.exerciseVCTableView?.reloadData() // tried to pass the table view from the previous scene to call here
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        // Want to save reload the table data of the scene this button transitions to
    }```
````

Comment: Just use a protocol to get callbacks. or just reload on ViewWillAppear method on the previous view.

Answer (score 0):

You may use delegate pattern for solving this. Delegate pattern is something, to delegate some work to other and return to the work after delegation is done.

Suppose `ViewController1` has UIBarButton , goes to `ViewController2`, some function done and return to `ViewController1`

let us take a protocol

```
protocol MyProtocol {
   func myFunction()
}
```

then in `ViewController2` add a delegate method. Assuming in `ViewController2`, you have to call a method `doMyWork` and some work will be done here, then you have to pop.

```
class ViewController2 {
    var delegate : MyProtocol?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       doMyWork()
    }

    func doMyWork() {
       // my works 
       delegate?.myFunction()
       self.navigationController.popViewController()
    }
}
```

now the viewController1 have to receive the delegate work has done.

in `viewController1`, in barButtonItem

```
class ViewController1 {

    @objc func barButton(_sender : UIBarButton) {
       let viewController = ViewController2()
       viewController.delegate = self 
       self.naviagtionController.pushViewController(viewController, animated : true)
    }

}
```

now you have to implement protocol method

```
extension ViewController1 : MyProtocol {
    func myFunction() {
       self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```